Power Automate Desktop - Convert DateTime to Text using "en-US" Locale
I want to format dates in Power Automate Desktop to a specific locale. I need to achieve this by converting date and time values into a desired string format while ensuring the locale is set to "en-US".
I attempted to use the Text.ConvertDateTimeToText action but encountered limitations as it does not accept a Locale parameter.
Text.ConvertDateTimeToText.FromCustomDateTime DateTime: PreviousMonth CustomFormat: $'''MMMM''' Locale: "EN" Result=> LastMonthName

To overcome this, I tried utilizing a PowerShell script within Power Automate Desktop. I do this by setting a DateTime variable, running a PowerShell script to format the date according to the "en-US" locale, and capturing the output to use in my automation flow but unfortunately it didn't work as well.
Is it even possible to change the locale somehow?
I tried to look it up, but I didn't find anything. Chat GPT also didn't help.
I need to get a format of "MMMM" (July, August.. )

You just need to use $date.ToString('MMMM') provided $date is a DateTime object.

In PowerShell code, you'd use something like (Get-Date).ToString('MMMM', [cultureinfo] 'en-US'). Please describe in what way your attempt to use a PowerShell script didn't work.
